# How do I call an entrypoint of an existing contract using SmartPy?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

How does one call an entrypoint of an existing contract using SmartPy?

For example, I'd like to be able to write a contract that calls the `getBalance` method of the [existing ETHtz FA1.2 contract](https://tzkt.io/KT19at7rQUvyjxnZ2fBv7D9zc8rkyG7gAoU8/entrypoints) and stores the return value in local state.

In other words, I'd like to complete this code:

```
import smartpy as sp

class MyETHtzBalanceContract(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init(num_ethtz = 0)

    @sp.entry_point
    def set_balance(self, ethtz_holder_address):
        # The address of the ETHtz FA1.2 contract.
        ethtz = sp.address("KT19at7rQUvyjxnZ2fBv7D9zc8rkyG7gAoU8")
        # How do I get this value for account `ethtz_holder_address`?
        # Note the ethtz contract defines a `getBalance` entrypoint of type
        # `(pair %getBalance (address :owner) (contract nat))`.
        self.data.num_ethtz = ...
```

BTW, I'm using the [SmartPy web IDE](https://smartpy.io/ide).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getBalance` entrypoint is a `view` entrypoint that requires a parameter of type `pair address (contract nat)`. ETHtz was written back when on-chain read functions were not available on Tezos, so a callback was required to retrieve values from another contract.

```
class ETHtzBalance(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init(
            ethtz_bal = sp.nat(0),
            ethtz_address = sp.address("KT19at7rQUvyjxnZ2fBv7D9zc8rkyG7gAoU8")
        )
    
    @sp.entry_point
    def set_balance_callback(self, balance):
        sp.set_type(balance, sp.TNat)

        sp.verify(sp.sender == self.data.ethtz_address, "Not authorised")

        self.data.ethtz_bal = balance
    
    @sp.entry_point
    def set_balance(self, ethtz_holder_address):
        c = sp.contract(
            sp.TPair(sp.TAddress, sp.TContract(sp.TNat)), 
            self.data.ethtz_address, 
            "getBalance"
        ).open_some()
        sp.transfer(
            sp.pair(ethtz_holder_address, sp.self_entry_point("set_balance_callback")), 
            sp.tez(0), 
            c
        )
```

Be careful about the `SENDER` check in the callback whenever you use a view function.

Comment: Thank you, this works!